# Condensation Reaction

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, carbonyl-compounds

In the aldol condensation reaction of a ketone with an aldehyde, both having acidic alpha hydrogens present; what is the major product?

Is it formed from enol of the ketone, or of the aldehyde? Is it from the enol of the ketone, because aldehydes are more reactive towards nucleophilic addition? Confirming, just to be sure.

Furthermore, which aldol condensation products are usually neglected?

Comment: Depends on the identity of the aldehyde and the ketone, and how the reaction is ran. Practically speaking, we often first enolise one component irreversibly first before adding the other (usually the aldehyde)

Comment: The answer to these questions literally fills entire chapters of reference books...

Comment: The aldol condensation is usually conducted in base. We should be talking about enolates, not enols (acid medium). As Zhe has said, this a broad topic. Provide specific examples.